# What is the purpose of a fireplace mantel?

Tags: furniture, design

The fireplace mantel or mantelpiece, also known as a chimneypiece, originated in medieval times as a hood that projected over a fire grate to catch the smoke. The term has evolved to include the decorative framework around the fireplace, and can include elaborate designs extending to the ceiling.

[image: Modern fire surround/mantel design]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I'm not sure this is strictly answerable because it involves some speculation. Over here mantel exclusively refers to the projecting board (basically a shelf) above the fire, and its sole purpose seems to be to hold nick nacks! On a more serious note, its sole practical value as part of the fireplace installation seems to be to direct smoke slightly away from the wall above the fire, to prevent staining, although other aspects of the fireplace's design should be the primary means to prevent this occurring.

Comment: It needs to be said in the 21st century that it is **not** a place for your flat panel television. *I find it amusing that the photo is not even a "real" fire place*.

Comment: The OP is encouraged to do their own research. Even though Wikipedia is much maligned, it is a good starting place for questions like this. I can't find fault with the first such hit I get when I search for "mantel". This might be slightly on-topic, in that the reason for mantels gave builders and carpenters plenty of work, and this work eventually turned into an opportunity for ever-increasing levels of ornamentation. I'm just not sure anyone here could answer this much better than the wikipedia page anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Originally, as you say, it was to support a hood over the fire.  Today it serves to cover the joint between the fireplace itself (usually lined with firebricks), and the rest of the wall.  Other than that, it is purely decorative.

Answer (score 0):

The picture provided is a bad example but the original purpose of building a thick layer of clay or stone possibly with tiles around it, is to hold the heat from the fire for a long time and provide heat in the room even after the fire itself has finished.

The kind of heat that the stone gives is radiational heat, which is more comfortable to people than actual hot air. (just like radiators do as opposed to convectors) Like an infrared sauna, this makes your body warm even while the air has a lower temperature.

The most efficient and comfortable kind of fireplaces are not open like in the picture, but have a small opening with a door. this creates a more efficient fire, more heat, and more energy stored in the mantel.
Albeit less esthetically pleasing perhaps.

The fireplace mantel in an open fireplace has another function of making it possible to heat pots over the fire. If you have a hook under the mantel you can hang pots there to cook food or make tea, etc.

If you are thinking about a way of actually heating your house, you should not choose an open fireplace since the efficiency is only 10% (so you are mostly just heating the air outside your house) as opposed to a closed thick fireplace where the efficiency is up to 80% or 90%

Answer (score -2):

In early times the fireplace mantle also served as a "bar" for the visiting "gentlemen" of the Pub or home to rest their drinks as they warmed their bodies as they enjoyed conversations of importance.

Comment: Welcome to WSE. This post requires substantially more information and backup to qualify as an answer

Comment: He is a knight, so his word cannot be questioned ;)